# Logical Operation (Logical OR) on 2 columns

Tags: t-sql

How do I return a OR based on 2 bit columns, Also they are nullable.

Comment: Updated my answer below with a simple select statement, maybe more what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

tsql uses the same bitwise operators that c# and other c languages use.  Namely the | for or, & for and, and ^ for exclusive or.

An example that might be most appropriate for your question:

```
select (column1 | column2) from [YourTable];
```

If you want to test all options you can try this block and test the various possibilities.

```
declare @col1 bit = 0 /** or 1 or null */
declare @col2 bit = 0 /** or 1 or null */
declare @col3 bit = null

set @col3 = (@col1 | @col2)
```

read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx